# Accidently deleted layer from Layers panel of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, georeferencing, panel

I accidently deleted a raster layer from my layers Panel (i used georeferencer to add it to my map) and i want to know if is there a way to get it back on my Layers panel without re-doing the whole "*georeferencer*" thing.

Answer (score 8):

During geo-referencing you are asked to save the new file somewhere. Check that location.

It could be good practice to save out the control points you create in case this issue ever happens again.

Comment: I found and "Drag and drop" the *.tiff file onto Qgis and it placed the image perfectly, apparently it saves the control points within the *.tiff file itself, Thanks !

Comment: Just for reference. it is a new file that is created; a geotiff, which is a geo-referenced raster.  The control points can be saved out into a separate file   that you can then use on other images of the same area.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that a world file was added to the original file. So try adding the file into QGIS using "Add Raster Layer" and see if it is where you had it.